# regex pattern for delete, arrows and escape keys

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a javascript code to restrict the keys that can be entered into a text box.

```
function keyRestricted(e) {
    var keypressed;
    var keychar;
    var keycheck;
    // IE - keyCode
    // Netscape/Firefox/Opera - which
    keypressed = e.keyCode || e.which;
    keychar = String.fromCharCode(keypressed);
    //alert(keychar);
    keycheck = /[a-zA-Z0-9\b]/;
    return keycheck.test(keychar);
} //keyrestricted
```

my regex is now `/[a-zA-Z0-9\b]/`, which allows alphanumeric and backspace.  I want to allow the delete, L/R arrows, and escape keys to work in firefox (3.6).

I am not sure sure what are the symbols for these keys.

In ie8, the escape key (and del/arrows) still is active even if the \e switch is excluded from the regex, when pressed, it resets/empties the text box.

In FF, I put the escape in the expression `/[a-zA-Z0-9\b\e]/`, but it does not seem to work for firefox, that is when the escape key is pressed, it does not reset/empty the text box.

what are the valid symbol for the regex to allow alphanumeric, L/R arrows, delete, escape?

Also, what is the translation for this `[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]`?
It was meant to be alphanumeric and hyphens.  But what is the slash infront of the hyphen since hyphen does not need a slash? and what is the `\_` for since the underscore is not matched by the expression?

TIA

Edit

The reason why using keycode numbers as suggested by nnnnn did not work for me (for other people?) is because the keycodes from 65-90 are for uppercase letters, even though some websites do claim that those keycodes work for both lower and upper cases.

This http://www.lookuptables.com/ website shows that lowercase letters are from 97-122.  Unfortunately, this range has some unmapped overlaps with some characters.  For example, the \ character is listed as having 220 keycode.  But my filter to deactivate of keycodes > 122 would still allow the \ to get through.  There are other examples.

I have tested this using my laptop keyboard and an external full size keyboard.

Edit 2

I have combined both the regex and the keycode arguments into one function.  The function works in principle, but due to crazy keycode conflicts, it does not work for the % sign.  It requires both the onkeydown and onkeypress to catch all the keys (except the % key). See my discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235813/javascript-regex-for-key-event-input-validations-troubleshooting-help)[javascript regex for key event input validations troubleshooting help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235813/javascript-regex-for-key-event-input-validations-troubleshooting-help)

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function keyRestricted(evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    var keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);
    //alert(keychar);
    var keycheck = /[a-zA-Z0-9]/;
    // backspace || delete || escape || arrows
    if (!(key == 8 || key == 27 || key == 46 || key == 37 || key == 39)) {
        if (!keycheck.test(keychar)) {
            theEvent.returnValue = false; //for IE
            if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault(); //Firefox
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    Please modify the contents of the text field.
    <input 
        type="text" value="" 
        onKeypress="return keyRestricted(event)" 
        onKeydown="return keyRestricted(event)" 
    />
</body>
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to use a regexp? Simply checking `keypressed` against the codes of delete etc. would be more straight-forward.

Comment: The keycodes for all of the keys can be found [here](http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx). In your function, what's the point of your `else if(e.which)`? If `e.which` is not defined your code just carries on anyway with `keypressed` undefined, which probably isn't what you intend. (But on the other hand if you're sure that `e.which` will be defined then why the `if`?)

Comment: I have tried the other methods that have been shown on this site.  They don't seem to work/behave the way that I intend for my script to work.  This method works best, but I need those switches for those keys.

Comment: See my answer below. It gives you some reliable ways to do this without using regular expressions. Note though that I wouldn't recommend doing it at all: you're usually better off validating the field `onchange`, `onblur` or `onsubmit`, unless you have a rock-solid way to stop the user pasting and/or drag'n'dropping invalid characters (and if you do you're the only one). In any case don't forget you'll have to validate it again server-side anyway.

Comment: Example, the keycode for right arrow is 39, what does that translate to in regex switch?

Comment: It doesn't, that's the point. Not all keys have a corresponding character value that you can put in a string. Don't use regex for this. Regex is a great tool, but it doesn't solve _all_ problems.

Comment: I am doing oninput (similar to onchange), I do have another set of validation to screen for invalid characters if drag and drop occurs.  I have spent many hours and this appears to be the most compatible routine for my need.  I just need the conversion from the keycodes to the regex switches.

Comment: Regex tests strings of characters. Not all keys have a corresponding character and therefore you can't use Regex to process those keys. Another way to put it is that those keys are invisible to Regex. _All keys have a corresponding keycode so you can easily test for them_ without _Regex_, and you can easily fit such a test into the function in your question by testing whether your `keypressed` variable matches the numeric codes for the keys you care about (as in my answer). **Regex is the wrong tool for this job.** Accept it and move on (as I'm going to).

Comment: P.S. You mentioned using `oninput`. According to MDN, "This event is only called when the text displayed would change, thus it is not called when the user presses non-displayable keys." So it won't work for arrow keys anyway. And isn't supported in older versions of IE or some other browsers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, Regex - or at least the JavaScript version - doesn't let you test for some of those "special" characters like escape and the arrow keys (though I believe you can test for backspace).

I prefer to implement this sort of thing with a standard `if` statement:

```
var keypressed = e.which || e.keyCode;

if ((keypressed >=65 && keypressed <= 90) // letters
    || (keypressed >=48 && keypressed <= 57) // digits
    || keypressed === 8 // backspace
    || keypressed === 27 // escape
    || keypressed === 46 // delete
    || (keypressed >= 35 && keypressed <= 40) // end, home, arrows
    // TODO: shift, ctrl, alt, caps-lock, etc
    ) {
  // do something
}

// If the keys you care about don't follow any particular pattern
// a switch might be more convenient:
switch (keypressed) {
  case 8:
  case 27:
  case 46:
     // valid key, do something
     break;
  default:
     // invalid key, do something else
     break;
}


// You can also do something like this:    
var permittedKeyCodes = {
  "8" : true,  // backspace
  "27" : true, // escape
  "46" : true  // delete
};
if (permittedKeyCodes[keypressed]) {
  // do something
}
```

If you use the latter approach, it would be more efficient to define the `permittedKeyCodes` object outside your function.

There are various places ([here's one](http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx)) where you can get a list of all of the keycodes.

Note that if you're trapping the keydown or keyup event the keycodes returned are associated with the keys, not the characters, so e.g., upper and lowercase A both have the same code. The keypress event works differently.

Comment: thanks nnnnnnnnnn, I have been working with similar codes as yours.  Either I coded wrong or incomplete, it did not work as intended.  I will give your code a try.  BTW, can you answer the syntax question in my last paragraph? TIA.

Comment: Extra backslashes are (usually) ignored. I would expect that expression to match on letters, numbers, hyphens and underscores.

Comment: It actually does not match underscore. That is why I am perplexed by it.

Answer (score 2):

Just read through http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html. It will tell everything you need to know to solve this.

A summary:

- You'll need to use the `keydown` (not `keypress`) event to detect non-printable keys such as arrow keys
- The `keyCode` property of the event will then work in all browsers, so there's no need for the `which` property.
- `keyCode` has no relation to the character typed in `keydown` and `keyup`, so do not attempt to obtain a character from the event.
- Opera only allows you to suppress the default browser behaviour in the `keypress` event (not `keydown`), so to support Opera, you'll need to handle the `keypress` event as well, and set a flag in the `keydown` event for the `keypress` handler to check.

Comment: Thanks, I decided that it is not worth the trouble with having to account for inconsistencies.