# javascript regex for key event input validations troubleshooting help

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am writing this code to detect and allow only alphanumeric and backspace/del/arrow key events in the textbox.  It works as intended Except that it does not prevent the `%` sign, the single quote `'` and period `.` to show up.  I have tested on different browsers on localhost, w3cschool website, my laptop keyboard and an external usb keyboard.  Please look over the code to see why those keys are allowed and to see whether it is the problem with the regex/filter or the keyboards' transmission of charcodes.

TIA

Edit 
If I use onkeydown event like Prusse suggested, the script will disallow the period or single quote to appear, but it will now allow all the shift/numbers characters to appear !@#$%^&* etc.

When I use both the onkeydown and onkeypress events together (as the code is now), it will restrict the entries to what I want EXCEPT for the `%` sign. I don't understand why the `%` sign won't get filtered.

If I just change the keycheck variable to just keycheck = /%/; then the % sign is filtered (yes, even though the code say to allow % sign).  Very weird. I am using just a regular dell laptop english keyboard.

```
<head>        
   <script type="text/javascript">

      function keyRestricted(evt) {
          var theEvent = evt || window.event;
          var key      = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;

          var keychar  = String.fromCharCode(key);
          //alert(keychar);
          var keycheck = /[a-zA-Z0-9]/;  

          if (!(key == 8   ||  
                key == 27  ||
                key == 46  || 
                key == 37  || 
                key == 39 )) { // backspace delete  escape arrows

                if (!keycheck.test(keychar)) {          
                theEvent.returnValue = false; //for IE

                    if (theEvent.preventDefault) 
                         theEvent.preventDefault(); //Firefox
                    //alert ("key allowed");
                }   
           }  
      }
   </script>

</head> 

<body>
    Please modify the contents of the text field.
    <input type="text" onKeypress="return keyRestricted(event)" value="" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keypress event don't use to be fired for the arrow keys, backspace key and stuff like that. You don't need to check for that.

In this event you got the charcode representing the key pressed and happens that

```
% charcode 37
. charcode 46
' charcode 39
```

In the keypress event the shift status is already applied(eg.: a charCode 97, A charcode 65). If you need to have some special effect on keys that don't generate characters press you need to listen for keydown/keyup events in those you got keycodes, they are fired for every key in the key board and the shift status is not applied, when you press the key for "A" don't matter if shift is pressed(or caps lock on) you always get 65.

Edit:

Just remove the first if.

Edit:

Try:

```
function keyRestricted(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var rv = true;
  //var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  var key = (typeof theEvent.which === 'undefined') ? theEvent.keyCode : theEvent.which;
  if (key && (key !== 8)){
    var keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);
    var keycheck = /[a-zA-Z0-9]/;
    if (!keycheck.test(keychar) )
    {
      rv = theEvent.returnValue = false;//for IE
      if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();//Firefox
    }
  }
  return rv;
}
```

Did test it on Firefox, Chrome and IE(9-7) and it seem to do want you want.
Sorry, did post the wrong code, try this one =)

Comment: Thanks Prusse for catching that, apparently those keycodes overlaps for the left/right arrows and del keys.  Taking out those keycodes won't allow the arrows and del keys to be active in firefox 3.6.  I am not sure why the overlapping of keycodes occurs since the period is keycode 190 according to this chart http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx

Comment: If you want to deal with key codes listen for the keydown event.

Comment: If I use onkeydown event, the script will not allow the period or single quote to appear, but it will now allow all the shift/numbers characters to appear !@#$%^&* etc.  When I use both the onkeydown and onkeypress events, it will prevent all the above except for the % sign.  I don't understand why the % sign won't get filtered.

Comment: Thanks Prusse for the latest code, but it does appear that I need to include the keycode conditions for the arrow/del/bkspace keys for it to work in firefox 3.6.  Without that condition, my firefox 3.6 does not work for those keys.  The percent sign and the left arrow keys do seem to map to the same keycode, and there seem to be a bug that prevents javascript to filter out the percent sign.  It might be that the % sign is a javascript problem, not a regex problem.

Comment: Thanks for the latest effort, it still does not work in Firefox 3.6 without explicitly adding the keycodes for the arrows, but if the left arrow code is added, the % sign will also get through.

Comment: Sorry, but I am testing on Firefox 3.6.20 and the arrows work with this code and the `%` is blocked... I can't help if I can't reproduce the problem sorry again.

Comment: You can try look for a library(like JQuery) to help handling the events or know the behavior of the browsers. IE and Chrome don't seem to fire(keypress) for the arrow keys. FF defines `which === 0` for the arrow keys and `keyCode === 0` for "character keys". When Chrome fires `keyCode === charCode`. Hope this helps.